# Getting Error while creating contact through xConnect in Sitecore9

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I am getting an exception/error while I am creating contact though xConnect Code,

below is my code:

```
using (var client = CreateClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var source = "Subcribe.Form";
                    var id = CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N");
                    CurrentTracker.Session.IdentifyAs(source, id);
                    var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(source, id);
                    var expandOptions = new ContactExpandOptions(
                        CollectionModel.FacetKeys.PersonalInformation,
                        CollectionModel.FacetKeys.EmailAddressList);
                    Contact contact = client.Get(trackerIdentifier, expandOptions);
                    SetPersonalInformation(GetValue(firstNameField), GetValue(lastNameField), contact, client);
                    SetEmail(GetValue(emailField), contact, client);
                    client.Submit();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

I am getting error on `client.Submit()` method , as below:

```
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: {
  "Message": "Operation failed: One or more dependencies failed",
  "ExceptionMessage": "One or more dependencies failed",
  "ExceptionType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.DependencyFailedException",
  "StackTrace": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Scaled database was not configured properly: the range shard map has to be configured.",
    "ExceptionType": "Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Failures.ScaledDatabaseConfigurationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Data.SqlServer.Configuration.ElasticScaleConnectionManager.GetRangeShardMap(String rangeShardMapName)\r\n   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Data.SqlServer.Configuration.ElasticScaleConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass37_0.<GetRangeMappings>b__0()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Data.SqlServer.Configuration.MemoryCacheManager.AddOrGetExistingFromCache[T](String key, Func`1 valueFactory)\r\n   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Data.SqlServer.Configuration.ElasticScaleConnectionManager.MapKeysToShards[TPartitionKey,TEntityKey](String rangeShardMapName, IReadOnlyCollection`1 keys)\r\n   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Data.SqlServer.Managers.SqlDataRecordsManager`2.<GetAsync>d__49.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Data.SqlServer.SqlDataProvider.<GetDeviceProfilesById>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<>c__DisplayClass440_0`1.<<ToAsyncEnumerable>b__1>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AnonymousAsyncIterator`1.<MoveNextCore>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.<MoveNext>d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectManyAsyncIterator`2.<MoveNextCore>d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.<MoveNext>d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<ForEachAsync_>d__174`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Sitecore.XConnect.Service.RepositoryGetInvoker.<UpdateGetOperations>d__7`2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Sitecore.XConnect.Service.RepositoryGetInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<<Execute>b__19>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Sitecore.XConnect.Service.RepositoryGetInvoker.<FailOperationsOnException>d__5.MoveNext()"
  }
}
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.Get[TEntity](IXdbContext context, IEntityReference`1 reference, ExpandOptions expandOptions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<GetDevice>b__1(IXdbContext xdbContext)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
```

I checked the xConnect collection URL and its up and running as below:

[image]

Below is my connection string for xconnect collection:

```
<add name="xconnect.collection" connectionString="https://Sitecore9.Xconnect" />
```

Comment: Could you open ShardMapManager database in SQL Server and query ShardsGlobal and ShardMappingsGlobal tables?

Comment: Can u check if you have done this on your web.config <add key="AllowInvalidClientCertificates" value="true" />?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? having the same problem

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Comment: @Żubrówka: Have you been able to fix it? I am getting the same error.

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi: Have you been able to fix it? I am getting the same error.

Comment: @NutsAndBolts I need to check, I have been working on other branches lately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to manually check the shards assignemnt in the [projectname].Collection.ShardMapManager?

If not, you can try this sql script to see if  the server name and the database name are correct

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP (1000) [ShardId]
      ,[Readable]
      ,[Version]
      ,[ShardMapId]
      ,[OperationId]
      ,[Protocol]
      ,[ServerName]
      ,[Port]
      ,[DatabaseName]
      ,[Status]
  FROM [{projectname}.Collection.ShardMapManager].[__ShardManagement].[ShardsGlobal]
```

And based on the information you see there you can create a update query to modify the servername accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several possibilities like:

1. Ambiguity in the xConnect DLL reference. `Sitecore XConnect` provides some default collection models to save user data like Personal Information, Email, Address, etc. the complete list you can find in an assembly named `Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.dll`.
2. Check null condition with Contact variable.
3. What is the code written into your CreateClient() method? For example:

```
using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
```

4. Change the syntax of your GetContact method as it should be:

> ```
> Contact contact = client.Get<Contact>(trackerIdentifier, expandOptions);
> ```

instead of

```
Contact contact = client.Get(trackerIdentifier, expandOptions);
```

For more details about the implementation you can follow the below links:

1. [Set contact facets](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/set-contact-facets.html)
2. [Work with Custom Facet in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/06/work-with-custom-facet-in-sitecore-9.html)